# Neo4j -Failed to add Bidirectional ralationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a newbie to neo4j, I started building relationships between the nodes. Uni directional relationships are created properly without throwing any error but the bi-directional relationship is throwing the syntax error.
Here goes my query:

```
MATCH(a{word:"nothing"}),(b{word:"review"})
CREATE a-[r:coocr{val:1}]-(b)
RETURN r,s
```

Then ended up with this:

```
MATCH(a{word:"nothing"}),(b{word:"review"})
CREATE a-[r:coocr{val:1}]->(b)
CREATE a<-[s:coocr{val:1}]-(b)
RETURN r,s
```

How can I reduce the no.of relationships using bidirectional relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j doesn't support creating bidirectional relationships, but you can query from either direction without any difference in performance.

If you want to represent different values/states going to/from then you'll want to create a relationship going in each direction.  Otherwise you should just creating it in whatever direction makes most senses (or arbitrarily in some cases) and query bidirectionally like this:

```
MATCH (a{word:"nothing"})-[rel:coocr]-(b{word:"review"})
RETURN rel
```

Note that there's no greater than or less than to represent the end of the arrow.

Comment: @Brain Underwood : Thankyou.

Comment: Adding property to the relationship not affecting                                   MATCH (a{word:"nothing"})-[rel:coocr{val:2}]-(b{word:"review"})
RETURN rel

Comment: Do you mean that if you put the `{val: 2}` into the relationship it's returning relationships where `val` is not 2?

Comment: (no rows)   ...Returned 0 rows in 14 ms. ....This is the result for the above query

Comment: If you don't have any relationships where the `val` property equals `4` then that makes sense.  Is that the case?

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake that returning a relationship which does not exists.

Comment: Got my mistake. Thankyou again